# Excel - how to calculate a score based on two fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a field called "Risk Score" that is based on two different fields without using nested if loops.

The two fields are "Likelihood of Risk" and "Impact of Risk" where the likelihood will be inputted as a % between 0-100% and the impact inputted as either high, medium, low.

Below is an example of the two fields and the calculated fields:

[image]

Below is the scoring I would like to derive in the third field based on the two fields.
[image]

I don't think I could use Index Match Match since the likelihood score is based on a range and not a specific value.

Please let me know if you have ideas on how I should create the formula for Risk Score. Thanks!

Comment: That's a pretty rudimentary row by column index lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ranges of %s to the minimums:

[image]

Then a simple INDEX/MATCH/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$E$5,MATCH(H3,$B$3:$B$5,1),MATCH(G3,$C$2:$E$2))
```

[image]